# How to go ahead with data migration through server using OPEN QUERY and creating a procedure from SQL Anywhere to MS SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlanywhere, data-integration

I have written this code and I am getting:

> incorrect syntax near '@vartablename'.

```
Declare @vartablename char;


While (Select Count(*) From TABLENAMES Where processed=0) > 0
Begin


 select * into @vartablename FROM openquery([PROGENYREAD],'select * from @vartablename  ');

 Update TABLENAMES Set Processed = 1 Where table_name = @vartablename;

End
```

Comment: Are you running this query in MSSQL using a linked server connection?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a question without expected behaviour and the current behaviour is off topic

Comment: @JPF YES. I am using linked server named progenyread